# How to generate the nth number that consists only of even digits?

Tags: c++, c++11, math, mathematical-optimization

I'm novice to Programming. I can find numbers consisting of even digits  but my algorithm complexity is O(n). For large `n` my algorithm is too slow. So I need a more efficient algorithm. Can anyone help me?

For example, the first numbers with even digits are 0 , 2 , 4 , 6 , 8 , 20 , 22 , 24 , 26 , 28 , 40 etc. 2686 is another example of a number with even digits.

Here is my code: http://ideone.com/nsBzej

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long int a[10],b[20];
long long int powr(int i)
{
    long long int ans=5;
    for(int j=2;j<=i;j++)
    {
        ans=ans*5;
    }
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    //freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    //freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);

    long long int n,s,sum,p;
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int j=1;j<=t;j++)
    {
        s=20,sum=0;
        a[1]=0, a[2]=2, a[3]=4, a[4]=6, a[5]=8;

        for(int i=1;i<=17;i++)
        {
            b[i]=s;
            s=s*10;
        }

        cin>>n;
        for(int i=17;i>=1;i--)
        {
            p=powr(i);
            while(p<n)
            {
                sum=sum+b[i];
                n=n-p;
            }
        }

        printf("Case %d: %lld\n",j,sum);
    }
}
```

It is complexity O(n). But I get wrong verdict.

Comment: What is your definition of "even digit"? Why is 10 not an "even digit"?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I think he means that he wants to find only numbers that have all digits even: 10 has 1 as a digit which is odd.

Comment: @Wallkan: Smells like homework XD

Comment: dear, It's recent contest problem .This contest are finished 2 days ago..I'm try solve this 2 days but I'm not success .

Comment: Since you didn't present any programming problem or any code you are having problem with, this question is off-topic for stackoverflow. You could try math exchange.

Comment: @user2079303: `10` is neither an even nor an odd _digit_.

Comment: Dear,@2501. I need efficient solving idea how to solve this problem.According @Wallkan below comment idea isn't working 1 second.It's getting verdict timelimit.

Comment: The answer is 224682000000000000. The algorithm is simple: calculate 1000000000000 in base 5, then replace every digit `d` with `2d`. Though very badly written, it is an interesting question which should be reopened IMO.

Comment: @Olaf `10` is not a *digit* at all, and neither is `20`. They are combinations of two separate *digits*.

Comment: @barakmanos For every on-topic question on SO, there exist infinite interesting questions that are also off-topic.

Comment: Dear, barak manos .Like this ..
 long long int ans=5;
    for(int j=2;j<=i;j++)
    {
        ans=ans*5;
    }
    return ans;

Comment: @2501: Due to the lack of actual code provided, it is probably more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com (or at least under a different tag here).

Comment: @AseemChakrabarthy: If you just need an algorithm, then please tag it accordingly. If you need a specific-language solution, then please share your code properly, so that this question will be worth reopening.

Comment: @barakmanos You paraphrased my comment made a while ago.

Comment: @user2079303: Great, you got the point of my comment:-)

Comment: Dear,@barakmanos,thanks i got it.

Comment: @barakmanos it maybe start from 0th. (_n = 1 so, answer = 0_ from Aseem's commnet)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: answer = 0?

Comment: @barakmanos see this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327544/how-to-generate-n-1000-000-000-000-nth-even-digits-consist-number-in-c-tim#comment65986970_39327625)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I still don't understand why the answer could be 0. I would understand if you said that the answer was one number before or after 224682000000000000, but why would it be 0???

Comment: @AseemChakrabarthy: Convert 1000000000000 to base 5. Replace every digit `d` with `2d`. Time complexity is `O(log(1000000000000))`, where log is on base 5 (not that it matters for the sake of complexity).

Comment: @barakmanos case of 1st is 0. i.e 224680888888888888

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: OK, so simply take my algorithm and apply it on 999999999999 instead.

Comment: Dear,barak monos Finding position. digit consist number for value n; if n=1 is position 1st and first position even digit consist is 0, Similarly n=2 is position is second event digit consist is 2 etc.

Comment: @barakmanos yes, I know.

Comment: Thanks #BLUEPIXY for editing .

Comment: Is the actual question "how can I generate the 1e12th number whose digits are all even"?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned long long nth = 1000000000000ULL-1;//-1: 1 origin
    unsigned long long k[30] = {0, 5};//28:Log10(ULL_MAX)/Log10(5) + 1
    unsigned long long sum = k[1];
    unsigned long long temp = 4;//4 : 2,4,6,8
    int i;
    //make table
    for(i = 1; i < 30 ; ++i){
        if(k[i] == 0){
            temp *= 5;//5 : 0,2,4,6,8 , 2digits: 4*5, 3digits: 4*5*5
            sum += temp;
            k[i] = sum;
        }
        if(k[i] > nth)
            break;
    }
    while(--i){//The same basically barakmanos
        int n = nth / k[i];
        printf("%d", n * 2);
        nth -= n * k[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", nth * 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you run on multiple numerical, table is created in advance.

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY .I got it.

Answer (score 0):

We need to find numbers made of 5 digits, 0, 2, 4, 6 and 8.
When we convert a number into base 5 number, it will only be made of numbers {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}.
It can be clearly seen that each digit in the required digit set {0, 2, 4, 6, 8} is double the digit in the corresponding index of the base-5 digit set.
So to find the n-th number made of only even digits follow the below mentioned steps

Step 1: Convert n to n-1 this is done so as to exclude zero.
Step 2: Convert n to 5 base decimal number.
Step 3: Multiply the above found number by 2. This is the required number

code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int help(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    vector< int> v;
    n = n - 1;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        v.push_back(n % 5);
        n = n / 5;
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        result = result * 10;
        result = result + v[i];
    }
    return 2*result;
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    cout << help(2) 
        << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bad practices tend to attract downvotes even if the practice is relatively common among CP communities. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3966456 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3966456